# How to split reducer under 1 key?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to separate a reducer into N more combining together 1 key.

Say I have an initial state:

```
const STATE_INITIAL = {
    nested_component: {
        field1: 1,
        field2: 2
    },
    upper_field: 3
}
```

Then I have a reducer:

```
function reducer(state=STATE_INITIAL, action){
    switch(action){
        case ACTION_UPPER_FIELD:
            return ...
        case ACTION_GRID1:
            return ...
        case ACTION_GRID2:
            return ...
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**Why I want to do it?**

I want to have a component that I can reuse throughout the project. It would always come with its initial state and would have its reducer that I'd like to connect to the rest of the application.

**My solution**

One way I can think of is stacking `case`s for grid actions, providing it with `state.grid`and its own initial state and combing the result with the `state`:

```
const STATE_INITIAL = {
    nested_component: {},
    upper_field: 3
};


function reducer(state=STATE_INITIAL, action){
    switch(action){
        case ACTION_UPPER_FIELD:
            return ...
        case ACTION_GRID1:
        case ACTION_GRID2:
            return reducerGrid(state.grid, action);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const STATE_INITIAL_GRID = {
    field1: 1,
    field2: 2
};

function reducerGrid(state = STATE_INITIAL_GRID, action) {
        switch(action){
            case ACTION_GRID1:
                return ...
            case ACTION_GRID2:
                return ...
            default: 
                return state;
        }
}
```

Is there a standardized approach or is my solution fine? The things I don't like about it is the `default` in the `reducerGrid` seems redundant now and I am also not satisfied with having to repeat the actions in both reducers.

**My 2nd Solution**

```
function reducer(state=STATE_INITIAL, action){
    const stateGrid = reducerGrid(state.grid, action)
    let stateNew = state;
    if(stateGrid !== state.grid){
        stateNew = {...state, grid: ...stateGrid}
    }

    switch(action){
        case ACTION_UPPER_FIELD:
            return {...stateNew, ... };
        default:
            return stateNew;
    }
}
```

**3rd Solution**

```
function reducer(state=STATE_INITIAL, action){
    const stateNew = {...state, grid: ...reducerGrid(state.grid, action)};

    switch(action){
        case ACTION_UPPER_FIELD:
            return ...
        default:
            return stateNew;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found a solution I am satisfied with.

Using this method:

```
import R from 'ramda';

function splitReducers(reducers, rest) {
    return (state, action) => {
        const reducersPrepared = R.mapObjIndexed((reducer, key) => {
            return reducer(R.defaultTo({}, state)[key], action);
        })(reducers);

        const getUndefinedIfEmpty = R.ifElse(
            R.isEmpty,
            () => undefined,
            R.identity
        );

        const stateWithoutSplitKeys = R.pipe(
            R.omit(R.keys(reducers)),
            getUndefinedIfEmpty
        )(state);

        return R.merge(
            reducersPrepared,
            rest(stateWithoutSplitKeys, action)
        );
    }
}
```

I can write my state tree in the following way:

```
Ports: splitReducers({
                grid: reducerGrid,
            }, reducer);
```

This will result in the object with keys split:

```
{
  Ports: {
     grid: {...},
     isSaving: true,
     isVisible: false
  }
}
```

After applying the method the `root-reducer` is showing more of its state at the first glance:

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    pageAllocation: combineReducers({
        tabNetwork: combineReducers({
            popupNetworkTemplates: reducerPopupNetworkTemplates,
            gridPorts: splitReducers({  //                <----- HERE IT IS
                grid: reducerGridPortsOnly 
            }, reducerPorts),
        }),
        tabStorage: () => ({}),
        activeTab: reducerPortsActiveTab
    }),
```